# UTF-8 encoding problems in MySQL DB (php)

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8

I have problems with UTF-8 encoding in MySQL DB. I use HTML form to insert data in MySQL DB and PHP code to represent the data from DB. When I insert string `"ąčęėįšųū"` using HTML form, I see such `“Ä…ÄÄ™Ä—Ä¯Å¡Å³Å«”` symbols in DB in PHPMyAdmin. I don’t have problem with data representation on the WEB, the string `“Ä…ÄÄ™Ä—Ä¯Å¡Å³Å«”` is represented trough select function as "ąčęėįšųū". 
My goal is to store data `"ąčęėįšųū"` not `“Ä…ÄÄ™Ä—Ä¯Å¡Å³Å«”`. Do you know how to solve this problem?

**MySQL setting > my.ini**

init-connect=SET NAMES

utf8 collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci

character_set_server=utf8

**DB settings:**

Database Collation > utf8_general_ci

Table Collation > utf8_general_ci

Field “Title” collation > utf8_general_ci

**Apache > php.ini:**

default_charset="UTF-8"

**HTML form to submit data:**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="tournaments-action.php" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <p>
      <label for="textfield">Text Field:</label>
      <input type="text" name="title" id="textfield">
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
    </p>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

**PHP form for submiting data:**

```html
<?php
include("../config.php");

$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_REQUEST['title']);

// attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO tournaments (title) VALUES ('$title')";

if(mysqli_query($db, $sql)){
   $msg="Records added successfully.";
   echo "Loading";
} else{
 $msg="ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. ";
    echo "Loading";
}
// close connection
mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

Comment: try to use the `mysqli_set_charset()` function when creating the connection.

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: Hi, I tried to use mysqli_set_charset() but still I get the same result I mentioned above.

Comment: See "Mojibake" in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: Thank you @deceze for your link. I managed to fix this issue. Your tutorial is very precise.

Case closed ;)